# Max sum of 2 unique elements

Tags: algorithm

Let's say you are given an array and you have 2 boxes you can put unique elements in

```
{a,b,b,c,b,b,c,d}
```

You can start from any where in the array, but can only move towards the right. In each basket you can put only one type of element. eg if a is in the basket only a can come over it. You stop when you can't put an element in either box.

What's the max number of elements you can get from an array like this into the two boxes.

From this array the answer is 6 because if you start from index 1 you can have the 4b's in one basket and the two c's in the other so total 6.

Can someone explain an efficient algorithm for a problem like this because the array can get extremely big and can have many different types of elements inside

Comment: Isn't this as simple as finding the two elements that occur the most in the array?

Comment: but they have to be adjacent to each other like if you start from index 1 you can only move to the right one by one.

So if an array like {a,c,c,c,c,e,d,b,e,e,b,b,b,b,b,b,b}

Two elements occurring most are c and b but if you are starting from index 1 you get 4 c's and an e, but you can't go more forward because you can't put the d anywhere and you have to stop

Comment: @Alerra the two elements that occur the most in the array, would depend on the starting point

Comment: @mangusta is right

Comment: @arashid so you mean that we may put only adjacent elements? i.e. we can't skip 1 or more elements

Comment: Yes you may move only towards the right and you can't skip any element and if the element can't go in either of the boxes you stop. You need to give the max elements that can be put in the two boxes combined

Comment: {a,b,b,c,b,b,c,d} => {a, ab, abb, bbc, bbcb, bbcbb, bbcbbc, cd}

Comment: @m69 bbcbbc is correct answer, but I need help in finding the most efficient algorithm for this

Comment: That was a hint. If you can build that array, its longest element is the answer.

Comment: I was misunderstood, but now I get the question. I like @m69 's hint

Comment: @m69 Elegant. Is that solution O(n)?

Comment: @m69 can you provide pseudocode for an array like this {a,b,a,c,d,c,e,a,b}

Comment: @JimMischel Yes it is. While writing my answer I also realized that it isn't necessary to store the segments or even just the current segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate this while iterating over the input only once, and there's no need to store the segments. You only need to keep track of the two characters in the current segment, the length of the segment, and the number of identical characters at the end of the segment. So time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(1).

```js
function largestPair(input) {
    var len = 0;     // length of segment
    var run = 0;     // number of identical characters at end
    var max = 0;     // length of longest segment
    var cur = '';    // last character in segment
    var prv = '';    // other character in segment

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == cur) {      // same as last
            ++len;
            ++run;
        }
        else if (input[i] == prv) { // same as other
            prv = cur;
            cur = input[i];
            ++len;
            run = 1;
        }
        else {                      // new character
            prv = cur;
            cur = input[i];
            len = run + 1;
            run = 1;
        }
        if (len > max) max = len;
    }
    return max;
}
document.write(largestPair(['a','b','b','c','b','b','c','d']) + "<br>");
document.write(largestPair(['a','b','a','c','d','c','e','a','b']) + "<br>");
document.write(largestPair(['c','a','a','c','a','c','b','b','b']) + "<br>");
document.write(largestPair(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']) + "<br>");
document.write(largestPair(['a','a']) + "<br>");
document.write(largestPair(['a']) + "<br>");
```

Or, more concise but slightly less obvious:

```js
function largestPair(input) {
    var len = 0;     // length of segment
    var run = 0;     // number of identical characters at end
    var max = 0;     // length of longest segment
    var cur = '';    // last character in segment
    var prv = '';    // other character in segment

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == cur) {
            ++len;
            ++run;
        } else {
            len = (input[i] == prv ? len : run) + 1;
            run = 1;
            prv = cur;
            cur = input[i];
        }
        if (len > max) max = len;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution, in Java, that only needs a single pass and doesn't require additional storage:

```
static int max2Run(String[] a)
{
    int e1 = 0; 
    int e2 = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(int k=0, i=1; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != a[i-1])
        {
            if(a[i] != a[e1] && a[i] != a[e2])
            {
                max = Math.max(max, i-e1);
                e1 = k;
                e2 = i;
            }
            k = i;
        }
    }
    return Math.max(max, a.length-e1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] a1 = {"a","b","b","c","b","b","c","d"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1) + " " + max2Run(a1));

    String[] a2 = {"c","a","a","c","a", "c", "b","b","b"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2) + " " + max2Run(a2));

    System.out.println();

    String[] a = new String[]{"a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"};
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Collections.shuffle(s);
        s.toArray(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a) + " " + max2Run(a));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[a, b, b, c, b, b, c, d] 6
[c, a, a, c, a, c, b, b, b] 6

[a, c, b, c, b, c, a, a, b] 5
[b, b, a, c, a, a, c, b, c] 5
[a, c, b, a, b, c, b, c, a] 4
[c, a, a, b, c, b, b, c, a] 5
[a, c, a, b, b, a, c, b, c] 4
```

Comment: For [c, a, a, c, a, c, b, b, b] answer should be 6 because caacac

Comment: Thanks @arashid. The algorithm is actually correct, I was trying to be too clever in the test code and was printing the unshuffled array. Fixed it now.

Comment: Yes your algorithm is correct also. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a loop that acts as each item as the index.

Then, create array for number of elements that each start index can contain.

Then after it, create a loop to check which index have the greatest number of elements in it.
For example:

```
elements[numElementsInArray];
for(int i=0; i<numElementsInArray; i++)
{
object element1 = array[i];
object element2 = null;
    for(int j=i; j<numElementsInArray; j++){

        if(array[j]==element1)
            elements[i]++;
        else if(element2!=null && array[j]==element2)
            elements[i]++;
        else if(element2==null){ element2=array[j]; elements[i]++; }
        else break;
    }    
}
```

// after that loop, create a loop on elements[] which number have the highest value.
This is just an idea, i just typed this code an haven't tested it, don't copy paste. Create your own code. 
I also created two objects element1 and element2 for the two baskets.
At first, i set element1 for the first of index i, so that it will be the first item on basket. Then inside of the another loop, you will check if element2 is occupied or null. If the succeeding items is not equal to either element1/2, it will break and set another element1/2 and another incrementing to element[].

Comment: Thanks. Could you try to write an actual compilable version of your idea?